# DQN Agent not converging

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to Deep Learning and I am trying to create a DQN agent for a custom environment that I have created where the state is the combination of the agent's position and a 2D matrix of 0s and 1s that tells the agent whether each user is requesting a service or not. The state matrix has 3 rows (because we have 3 users) and 3 columns (because we have 3 types of users).

Example:

```
(
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 0)
)
```

Which means that user0 and user2 (`row[0] and row[2]`) are requesting a service, and user1 is not. (There can be at most one column with the value of one in each row)

The action is a combination of 3 things, but for now I am focusing on the second element of the action, which a 2D matrix of 0s and 1s (or rather 'O' for 1 and 'Z' for 0) with 4 rows (equal to the number of resources the agent has and that will be given to the users) and 3 columns (equal to the number of users).

Examaple:

```
(
 ('O', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'Z'),
 ('Z', 'Z', 'O')
)
```

Which means that user0 and user2 were given resource0 and resource3.

Each resource can be given to one user and each user can be given one resource at each time step.

A reward is returned by the step() method in the environment when resources were allocated to the users that requested a service, and a penalty is returned if a resource was given to a user that did not ask for a service (meaning that in the state matrix, the row would look like this (0, 0, 0)).

I decided to create a Convolutional Neural Network with the input being a 2D matrix of 3 rows and 3 columns.

The idea is that the CNN would scan each row and extract the 1 if it exists, else it extracts the 0 with the MaxPooling layer, then for each row of the input, it will choose one of 2 values as output (like in the classification examples), where the first value means that the user will not be allocated resources and the second value means the user will be allocated resources.

The output will then be an array of 0s and 1s, and afterwards I have a method that will choose resources for each value of the array that is equal to 1.

Here is the code that creates the CNN:

```
def create_cnn(self, width, height, depth=1, regress=False): # for the matrix
        # initialize the input shape and channel dimension
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        output_nodes = 2
        
        # define the model input
        inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
        
        input_layer = Input(shape=(height, width, depth))
        conv1 = Conv2D(height, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=inputShape, data_format='channels_last') (input_layer)
        
        pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 3), strides=None, padding="valid")(conv1)

        output_layer1 = Dense(output_nodes, activation="softmax")(pool1) 

        model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer1)

        # return the CNN
        return model
```

Here is the method that builds the model:

```
def _build_model(self):
        # create the CNN models
        cnn = self.create_cnn(3, len(env.UEs))
        
        opt = Adam(lr=self.learning_rate, decay=self.epsilon_decay)
        
        cnn.compile(loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error", optimizer=opt)
        
        return cnn
```

Here is the replay method:

```
def replay(self, batch_size, change_eps): # method that trains NN with experiences sampled from memory
        minibatch = sample(self.memory, batch_size) 
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch: 
            actions = sorted(env.getActionsAsDict(action[1]).items()) # returns list of tuples
            print("Actions in replay", actions)
            target = reward 

            if not done: # if not done, then predict future discounted reward
                sub_next_state = self.addDims(next_state[1])
                predictions = self.model.predict(np.array(sub_next_state))[0]
                predictions_array = self.getPredictionsMaxArray(predictions)

                target = self.getTargetValues(predictions_array)
                
            sub_state = self.addDims(state[1])
            target_f = self.model.predict(np.array(sub_state))

            if isinstance(target, Sequence):
                target_f[0] = self.populateTargetFArrayVal(actions, target_f[0], target)
            else:
                target_f[0] = self.populateTargetFOneVal(actions, target_f[0], target)

            self.model.fit(np.array(sub_state), target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0) 
            
        if change_eps == True:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
            

def populateTargetFOneVal(self, actions, target_f, target):
        for action in actions: # list of tuples
            target_f[action[0]][0][action[1]] = target
            
        return target_f
        
def populateTargetFArrayVal(self, actions, target_f, target):
        for action in actions: # list of tuples
            target_f[action[0]][0][action[1]] = target[action[0]]
            
        return target_f
    
def addDims(self, matrix):
        sub_state = env.copyMatrix(matrix) # state[1]
        sub_state = np.expand_dims(sub_state, axis=0)
        sub_state = np.expand_dims(sub_state, axis=3)
        
        return sub_state

def getTargetValues(self, predictions_array):
        target = []
        for elt in predictions_array:
            target.append(reward + self.gamma * elt)
            
        return target
        
    
def getPredictionsMaxArray(self, predictions):
        predictions_array = []
        for row in predictions:
            predictions_array.append(np.amax(row))
            
        return predictions_array
```

This is the CNN summary:
[image: CNN Summary]

This is the CNN architecture:

[image: CNN Arch]

And this is the output (reward by episode):

[image: CNN Output]

Comment: Could you share a link to the entire code?